# Android's Webview cannot handle javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, android

My android application displays webpages(i used webview for it). .but javascript onthe wepage is not running in a webview .If i visit the same webpage through the Browser,javascript is running . How to run javascript in an application(using a webview)?

Answer (score 13):

#### Enable  Javascript! :

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

[**WebView : setJavaScriptEnabled**](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



I tried both,they didnt work for me.

Comment: it also support for mathjax-config? because my webview client not display some math function i googled a lot but nothing works@Elenasys

Answer (score 7):

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

> "By default, a WebView provides no
>   browser-like widgets, does not enable
>   JavaScript and web page errors are
>   ignored. If your goal is only to
>   display some HTML as a part of your
>   UI, this is probably fine; the user
>   won't need to interact with the web
>   page beyond reading it, and the web
>   page won't need to interact with the
>   user. If you actually want a
>   full-blown web browser, then you
>   probably want to invoke the Browser
>   application with a URL Intent rather
>   than show it with a WebView.
>
> ...
>
> However, you can modify the
>   WebSettings, such as enabling
>   JavaScript with
>   setJavaScriptEnabled()."

Comment: This answer is extremely importent OP, just because something CAN be done does not mean you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For Easy way you can use WebChromeClient, see in this [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=uVqp1zcMfbE).

If you want more control with js, you can use method with `addJavascriptInterface`, but you must create your html-page for this method ().
Look at [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#git%2FSamples%2FWebViewDemo).